# A software that can create multiple folders

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, windows-7

I need a free software for windows 7 that can create multiple folders if I enter the names of the folders separating them with semicolons. I have already tried text2folder. Anyone know of such application?

Comment: Why not create a batch file which splits the given text by semicolon and create a folder for each value?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Thanks for the suggestion but I don't know how to write such batch file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746556/create-folders-from-each-line-of-a-textfile-in-bat

Comment: Downvoters, may I know what's wrong with this post? Your feedback will help me improve it.